# Can't login to careers.stackexchange.com using Steam : Invalid claimed_id or identity (Contact:, Reference: )

Tags: support, jobs, login, openid

I'm trying to link my stackoverflow identity to my organization's page on careers.stackexchange.  I'm having trouble logging into careers at all.

I use myopenid.com (which is now dead) and steam to login to most stackexchange sites.

When I try to use the steam openid url, I do login to steam (confirmed by revisiting the page and it recognizes me.  However careers.stackexchange still doesn't recognize me.  It says: `Invalid claimed_id or identity (Contact: , Reference: )`

I'm using Opera (just in case that matters).

[image: screenshot of failure message]

Comment: I've resolved my issue by using another way to login.

Answer (score 3):

If you are logging in via steam, you should use this url as the openID URL: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/

If you don't use the correct url, you'll get the "invalid claimed id" message.  For example, it is incorrect to use a longer url: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/bunchofnumbers